# Rails Action Mailer Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Im trying to send HTML code as a variable using ActionMailer's ( Ruby on Rails default mailer ).

I have an example bellow with an easy variable ( thats also HTML code )

---

```
def newsletter // ==> my method to send
@template = "<h1>wait what ?</h1>"
mail(to: "email@test.com", subject: "test de newsletter")
end
```

---

```
newsletter.html.erb // ==> my html.erb file
<%= @template %>
<h1>wait what ?</h1>
```

---

the result I get is :

```
<h 1 > wait what ? </ h 1> // ==> cannot write h1 here tho 
<b>wait what ?</b>
```

---

```
// ==> in the  terminal the mail looks like this 
<body>
&lt;h1&gt;wait what ?;/h1&gt;
<h1>wait what ? </h1>
</body>
```

---

Maybe I can upload an entire file as template ?
How can I write HTML code in my variable ?

Comment: The usual practice is to put all the HTML in the html.erb file just a like a view.

Answer (score 0):

> Maybe I can upload an entire file as template ?

Yes, you can use an entire file as the template. It is called a view. See reference below.

> How can I write HTML code in my variable ?
> Use the `raw` method:

`<%= raw @template %>`

You may want to try this [ActionMailer walkthrough](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#walkthrough-to-generating-a-mailer).

Reference: [Create a Mailer View](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#create-a-mailer-view)

Answer (score 0):

In your view file(newsletter.html.erb) mark the string as trusted safe.

```
<%= @template.html_safe %>
```

Use raw if there are chances that the string will be nil.

```
<%= raw(@template) %>
```